# Need to remove XSD files link from xml file using code

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to remove link inside result tag by code.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd" xmlns="https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd">
  <data>
    <key>MailingGUID</key>
  <value>3699f54b-a05c-45d9-9f91-2d65fea9e2f3</value>
  </data><data>
    <key>OrderRef</key>
  <value>52177</value>
  </data>
</result>
```

But i want to empty result tag by code.I have used this code:

```
 XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();      
 xml.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml"));
 // var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
 var configuration = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("result");  
 if (configuration != null)
 {               
     // code...
 }
```

I need to remove links inside result tag.

Comment: Which of the links? There are three attributes on the result node that has links in their values.

Comment: @mortb i need to remove xsd files becuse they are creating problems.xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd" xmlns="https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of everything on the `<result>` element (including the xmlns), then do this:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

using (XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml")))
{
    xtr.Namespaces = false;

    xmldoc.Load(xtr);
}

xmldoc.DocumentElement.RemoveAllAttributes();
```

That will produce this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>
  <data>
    <key>MailingGUID</key>
  <value>3699f54b-a05c-45d9-9f91-2d65fea9e2f3</value>
  </data><data>
    <key>OrderRef</key>
  <value>52177</value>
  </data>
</result>
```

If you want to get rid of specific ones then use `RemoveAttribute(...)`.

Comment: i need to remove data inside <result> this :xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd" xmlns="https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd

Comment: can you please tell what i need to add in this code so i get value of   <key>OrderRef</key>
  <value>52177</value>.......right now i am able to get value of  <key>MailingGUID</key>
  <value>3699f54b-a05c-45d9-9f91-2d65fea9e2f3</value>

Answer (score 0):

Add at the top of your class file:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

and you may try this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml"));
xml.DocumentElement.RemoveAllAttributes();
xml.LoadXml(Regex.Replace(xml.OuterXml, @"xmlns="".*?""", m => ""));
```